# Unable to verify method call - Rhino mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am receiving an exception: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I am trying to evaluate if Location and Manufacturing classes method ResetAllProperties() are executed.

What em I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Engine
    {
        public Engine() { }

        public EngineStatus Status { get; internal set; }
        public virtual EngineLocation Location { get; set; }
        public virtual EngineManufacturing Manufacturing { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class EngineStatus
    {
        protected readonly Engine engine = null;

        public EngineStatus(Engine engine)
        {
            this.engine = engine;
        }

        public abstract void ResetAllProperties();
    }

    public class FirstEngineStatus : EngineStatus
    {
        public FirstEngineStatus(Engine engine) : base(engine) { }

        public override void ResetAllProperties()
        {
            this.engine.Location.ResetAllProperties();
            this.engine.Manufacturing.ResetAllProperties();
        }
    }

    public class EngineLocation
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public virtual EngineManufacturing Manufacturing { get; set; }
        public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; }

        public void ResetAllProperties()
        {
            this.CustomerName = null;
        }
    }

    public class EngineManufacturing
    {
        public Nullable<DateTime> EntryDate { get; set; }

        public virtual EngineLocation Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; }

        public void ResetAllProperties()
        {
            this.EntryDate = null;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ResetAllProperties_AssertWasCalled()
        {
            // Arrange
            var engine = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Engine>();
            var status = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<FirstEngineStatus>(engine);

            engine.Stub(action => action.Location.ResetAllProperties());
            engine.Stub(action => action.Manufacturing.ResetAllProperties());

            // Act
            status.ResetAllProperties();

            // Assert
            engine.AssertWasCalled(action => action.Location.ResetAllProperties());
            engine.AssertWasCalled(action => action.Manufacturing.ResetAllProperties());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asserting the behaviour of `Location` and `Manufacturing`, so these are the objects which should be mocked. Also, when checking that something happens use `Expects` not `Stub`. Everything else should be concrete. If you make `ResetAllProperties` methods virtual then the following works:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ResetAllProperties_AssertWasCalled()
{
    var location = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<EngineLocation>();
    var manufacturing = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<EngineManufacturing>();

    // Arrange
    var engine = new Engine
    {
        Location = location,
        Manufacturing = manufacturing
    };
    var status = new FirstEngineStatus(engine);
    location.Expect(action => action.ResetAllProperties());
    manufacturing.Expect(action => action.ResetAllProperties());

    // Act
    status.ResetAllProperties();

    // Assert
    location.VerifyAllExpectations();
    manufacturing.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

However, this seems like you are testing the implementation rather than the functionality. What do you actually want to test? It looks to me like you want to test that `CustomerName` and `EntryDate` are set to null. You can test this without using any mocking at all as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ResetAllProperties_AssertWasCalled()
{
    // Arrange
    var engine = new Engine
    {
        Location = new EngineLocation { CustomerName = "Dzenan" },
        Manufacturing = new EngineManufacturing { EntryDate = DateTime.Today }
    };
    var status = new FirstEngineStatus(engine);

    // Act
    status.ResetAllProperties();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNull(engine.Location.CustomerName);
    Assert.IsNull(engine.Manufacturing.EntryDate);
}
```

Comment: I would like to verify that ResetAllProperties() method is invoked on: status.ResetAllProperties(). it has nothing to do with ResetAllProperties() implementation.